# How to get limits in integral to the right hand side

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, mathdesign

I like the integral from `mathdesign`, but how can I get the limits to the right hand side?

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareSymbolFont{md}{OMX}{mdput}{m}{n} 
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Newint}{\mathop}{md}{90}
\begin{document}
\[A=\int_{0}^{b}\!\!\!f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\]
\[A=\Newint_{0}^{b}\!\!f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Guess: `\nolimits`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{md}{OMX}{mdput}{m}{n} 
\DeclareMathSymbol{\intop}{\mathop}{md}{90}
```

and LaTeX will change `\int` into your new symbol.

Normally `\int` is defined as

```
\intop\nolimits
```

exactly for getting, by default, the limits on the side.