# How to get the limits of an integral to the right instead to top and bottom

Tags: math-mode, formatting, amsmath, math-operators, unicode-math

Right now my integrals look like this

[image]

Is it possible to force it to look like

[image]

Thank you

Comment: To add more context, right now the top image is generated whenever I use $\int_{0}^b$

Comment: That's the default behavior of the command `\int`. To place the limits up  and down you invoke the command `\limits`. Are you sure you're not using it somewhere?

Comment: Related: [How to get limits in integral to the right hand side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/297744/5764)

Comment: What font are you using? Some fonts may produce outputs like the one you gave.

Comment: @Tolaso I'm using some silly template. But the answer right now seems to override whatever style the template is using

Comment: Sure because `\nolimits` enforces the limit to behave like they should behave.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `\nolimits` to toggle that on a single integral:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\newcommand*\dd{\!\mathop{}\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}
\[
  A = \int\nolimits_{0}^{b} f(x)\dd x
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The resulting limit looks very cute.